# Microsoft Word Document Recovery seems unresolvable

Tags: microsoft-word-2003

We work on a server (Windows Server 2003 Enterprise) that a bunch of us developers remote in using Remote Desktop Connection, and now every "other" time I open up word I get this Document Recovery pane:

[image]

As you can see, "Delete" and "Show Repairs" are disabled (I don't think this is my document).  "Open" or "Save As" works, but it never marks this document recovered, it just keeps coming up every "other" time I open up word.

I don't even care about this document.  How can I remove this document from the list so that it doesn't come up anymore?

**Update:**

As per Moab's comment, I had the user delete the file.  But the Document Recovery still shows up with that item every other time Word is opened.  The only difference now is that clicking on "Open" produces this (obvious) message:

[image]

How can I clear this list?  BTW, the user that owned this document was *never* getting the Document Recovery pane.

Comment: whoever created that file owns it (file permissions), so the owner needs to delete it, or you need to have the admin of the server log in to delete the file, its a permissions issue.

Comment: @Moab, perhaps your comment is worthy as an answer.

Comment: @Moab Actually, the document was deleted by the owner of the file.  But my version of Word still pops that document up in the Document Recovery (but can't open it now since it's not there).  Do you know of a "cache" list I need to clear out in a folder or registry?

Comment: @Moab Per the tag, Word 2003.

Comment: See this...http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/word-help/clear-the-history-of-recently-used-files-HP001168458.aspx

Comment: You might also try to repair Word...http://tipsforwordprocessing.com/word_2003_0050.html

Comment: Some reading here...http://support.microsoft.com/kb/822005

Comment: Another possibility: a zombie instance of Word has the document open.  Have the user who owns it quit Word, then go to Task Manager, check the Process list for instances of WINWORD.EXE ... select and end process on any that appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this article at Microsoft:

[Every other time that you open a document in Word, the document opens in recovery mode or you receive an error message](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/885380)

I ended up having to delete a value from this registry tree:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE
  \SOFTWARE
    \Microsoft
      \Windows NT
        \CurrentVersion
          \Terminal Server
            \Install
              \Software
                \Microsoft
                  \Office
                    \11.0
                      \Word
                        \Resiliency
                          \DocumentRecovery
```

There was an item in there named "F667E33" and when I looked inside it, the Binary Data showed the name of the file (binary, which explains why my registry search for the name of the file failed).

I simply deleted this item and the Document Recovery stopped coming up with that file in the list.